# Joint tables by column with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to tables with the same quantity of rows but with different quantity of columns, what I want is to join the tow tables but not adding more rows, instead of that i want to put the first table to the left of the other.

I've done this by far and with the table headers, things are pretty good, but with the rows thing get a little bit mixed:

```js
$('#boton').click(function(){
  appen();
});

function appen(){

  var head=$('#second thead tr th');
  var body=$('#second tbody tr td');
  i=0;
  $('#first').find('tr').each(function(){
      $(this).find('th').eq(0).before(head);
      $(this).find('td').each(function(){
         $(this).eq(0).before(body[i]);
         i++;
      });
  });
}
```

```css
table, td { border: 1px solid black; }
table { margin-bottom: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="first" class="merge">
  <thead>
    <tr >
        <th>num 1</th>
        <th>num 2</th>
        <th>num 3</th>
        <th>num 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="second" class="merge">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>num 5</th>
      <th>num 6</th>
      <th>num 7</th>
      <th>num 8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" id="boton" >boton</button>
<table class="result">
</table>
```

This is what I want:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|   num 5 |   num 6 |   num 7 |   num 8 |   num 1 |   num 2 |   num 3 |   num 4 |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|   5     |   6     |   7     |   8     |   1     |   2     |   3     |   4     |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|   5     |   6     |   7     |   8     |   1     |   2     |   3     |   4     |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

This is what I get:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|   num 5 |   num 6 |   num 7 |   num 8 |   num 1 |   num 2 |   num 3 |   num 4 |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|   5     |   1     |   6     |   2     |   7     |   3     |   8     |   4     |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|   5     |   1     |   6     |   2     |   7     |   3     |   8     |   4     |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: First table to the left of the second table would be `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`, not `5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4`

Comment: Well yes, is just an example, the thing is that I want to put one table at the left of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, much simpler:

```js
$('#boton').click(append);

function append() {
  var rows = $('#second tr');
  
  $('#first tr').each(function(i) {
    $(this).append(rows.eq(i).children());
  });
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="first" class="merge">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>num 1</th>
      <th>num 2</th>
      <th>num 3</th>
      <th>num 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="second" class="merge">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>num 5</th>
      <th>num 6</th>
      <th>num 7</th>
      <th>num 8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" id="boton">boton</button>
```

## Update

Here's a jQuery plugin for `$.fn.join()` and `$.fn.joinTo()`:

```js
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
  "use strict";

  // undefined is used here as the undefined global variable in ECMAScript 3 is
  // mutable (ie. it can be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really being
  // passed in so we can ensure the value of it is truly undefined. In ES5, undefined
  // can no longer be modified.

  // window and document are passed through as local variables rather than global
  // as this (slightly) quickens the resolution process and can be more efficiently
  // minified (especially when both are regularly referenced in your plugin).

  // A really lightweight plugin
  $.fn.join = function join(selector) {
    var $selector = $(selector);
    var rowSelector = arguments[1];
    var selectRows;
    
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
      rowSelector = "> *";
    }

    if (typeof rowSelector == "string") {
      selectRows = function selectRows($parent) {
        return $parent.find(rowSelector);
      };
    } else if (typeof rowSelector == "function") {
      selectRows = function selectRows($parent) {
        return $parent.find("*").filter(rowSelector);
      };
    } else {
      return this;
    }

    return this.each(function (table) {
      var $left = selectRows($(this));
      var $right = selectRows($selector.eq(table));
      
      // silently fail on tables with mismatching amount of rows
      if ($left.length == $right.length) {
        $left.each(function (row) {
          $(this).append($right.eq(row).children());
        });
      }
    });
  };
  
  $.fn.joinTo = function joinTo(selector) {
    var $self = this;
    var $selector = $(selector);
    var rowSelector = arguments[1];
    var selectRows;
    
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
      rowSelector = "> *";
    }

    if (typeof rowSelector == "string") {
      selectRows = function selectRows($parent) {
        return $parent.find(rowSelector);
      };
    } else if (typeof rowSelector == "function") {
      selectRows = function selectRows($parent) {
        return $parent.find("*").filter(rowSelector);
      };
    } else {
      return this;
    }

    return $selector.each(function (table) {
      var $left = selectRows($(this));
      var $right = selectRows($self.eq(table));
      
      // silently fail on tables with mismatching amount of rows
      if ($left.length == $right.length) {
        $left.each(function (row) {
          $(this).append($right.eq(row).children());
        });
      }
    });
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);

// demo
$('#join').click(function () {
  var $result = $("#first")
    .clone()
    .join($("#second").clone(), "tr")
    .attr('id', 'result');
  $('#result').replaceWith($result);
});

$('#joinTo').click(function () {
  var $result = $("#first")
    .clone()
    .joinTo($("#second").clone(), "tr")
    .attr('id', 'result');
  $('#result').replaceWith($result);
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

button {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="first" class="merge">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>num 1</th>
      <th>num 2</th>
      <th>num 3</th>
      <th>num 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="second" class="merge">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>num 5</th>
      <th>num 6</th>
      <th>num 7</th>
      <th>num 8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" id="join">$("#first").join("#second", "tr")</button>
<button type="button" id="joinTo">$("#first").joinTo("#second", "tr")</button>

<table id="result">
</table>
```

### Usage

#### `$(leftTables).join(rightTables[, rowSelector = "> *"])`

#### `$(rightTables).joinTo(leftTables[, rowSelector = "> *"])`

If the amount of rows mismatches for any two tables, the join is silently omitted for that pair of tables and they are returned un-mutated. These methods mutate the selection of `leftTables` and `rightTables`.

`rowSelector` can also be a function that gets passed to filter all descendants of each table to determine how rows should be joined. It is assumed that the columns of each row are simply all the children. By default, `rowSelector` selects only the children of each table, which is why it needs to be modified for actual `<table/>'s`.

Both the methods append the rows in `rightTables` to the rows in `leftTables` and return the joined `leftTables`.

Comment: Do I get bonus points if I implement this as a jquery plugin?

Comment: well, I am a beginer, don't know what you mean by jquery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the loop over `$(this).find("td")` expects both tables to have the same number of columns.

Instead of looping over cells, you should loop over rows, and just combine the rows by prepending the cells in the row from one table to the row of the other table.

```js
$('#boton').click(function() {
  appen();
});

function appen() {

  var head = $('#second thead tr th');
  var body = $('#second tbody tr');
  $("#first thead tr").prepend(head);
  $("#first tbody tr").each(function(i) {
    $(this).prepend(body.eq(i).children());
  });
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="first" class="merge">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>num 1</th>
      <th>num 2</th>
      <th>num 3</th>
      <th>num 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="second" class="merge">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>num 5</th>
      <th>num 6</th>
      <th>num 7</th>
      <th>num 8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" id="boton">boton</button>
<table class="result">
</table>
```